# How to connect a Hive Database on Google Cloud Dataproc to Tableau

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tableau-api, google-cloud-dataproc

I have created a Google Cloud Dataprocs cluster and then proceeded to create a Hive database and a table and populated the table with data. I now am trying to connect this table as a data source in Tableau but Iam unable to find a solution that works. To add, Iam using Tableau Desktop and have not install it on GCE.

Does Tableau Desktop support connecting to hive on Dataprocs in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned where your Tableau is installed, so here are couple of options:

- Have both Tableau and Dataproc running on the same VPC, and then you can open the HiveServer2 port (10002) in the VPC
- Install [Apache Knox](https://knox.apache.org/) by copying [this initialization action](https://github.com/yunus/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/knox) to a bucket of your choosing. Please notice that the README contains specific instructions for Hive

**Edit**
If you are using it just from your desktop, you can use ssh port forwarding to create a secure tunnel between your desktop and the cluster's master by running `gcloud compute ssh MYCLUSTER-m --project PROJECT --zone ZONE -- -L 10002:localhost:10002`. The Hive server should be available on localhost:10002.

Comment: Have updated my question. Is it not possible on Tableau Desktop?

Comment: That's what Knox is doing - opens the port to the web so it can be accessed also from your desktop, but it adds a security layer. I've listed another simpler solution in the answer.